# Efficient way to encode CDATA elements

Tags: c#, .net, xml, cdata, streamreader

Ok, I'm reading data from a stream using a StreamReader.  The data inside the stream is not xml, it could be anything.

Based on the input StreamReader I'm writing to an output stream using an XmlTextWriter.  Basically, when all is said and done, the output stream contains data from the input stream wrapped in a  element contained in a parent  element.

My problem is twofold.  Data gets read from the input stream in chunks, and the StreamReader class returns char[].  If data in the input stream contains a "]]>" it needs to be split across two CDATA elements.  First, how do I search for "]]>" in a char array?  And second,  because I'm reading in chunks, the "]]>" substring could be split across two chunks, so how do I account for this?

I could probably convert the char[] to a string, and do a search replace on it. That would solve my first problem.  On each read, I could also check to see if the last character was a "]", so that on the next read, if the first two characters are "]>" I would start a new CDATA section.

This hardly seems efficient because it involves converting the char array to a string, which means spending time to copy the data, and eating up twice the memory.  Is there a more efficient way, both speedwise and memory wise?

Comment: I've deleted my answer because I've decided I don't really know how XmlTextWriter works. The docs don't say what I expected they would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> second, because I'm reading in chunks, the "]]>" substring could be split across two chunks, so how do I account for this?

Indeed, you would have to keep back the last two characters in a queue instead of spitting them out immediately. Then when new input comes in, append it to the queue and again take all but the last two characters, search-and-replace over them, and output.

Better: don't bother with a CDATA section at all. They're only there for the convenience of hand-authoring. If you're already doing search-and-replace, there's no reason you shouldn't just search-and-replace ‘<’, ‘>’ and ‘&’ with their predefined entities, and include those in a normal Text node. Since those are simple single-character replacements, you don't need to worry about buffering.

But: if you're using an XmlTextWriter as you say, it's as simple as calling WriteString() on it for each chunk of incoming text.

Answer (score 4):

According to [*HOWTO Avoid Being Called a Bozo When Producing XML*](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/producing-xml/):

> [Don’t bother with CDATA sections](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/producing-xml/#cdata)
>
> XML provides two ways of escaping
>   markup-significant characters:
>   predefined entities and CDATA
>   sections. CDATA sections are only
>   syntactic sugar. The two alternative
>   syntactic constructs have no semantic
>   difference.
>
> CDATA sections are convenient when you
>   are editing XML manually and need to
>   paste a large chunk of text that
>   includes markup-significant characters
>   (eg. code samples). However, when
>   producing XML using a serializer, the
>   serializer takes care of escaping
>   automatically and trying to
>   micromanage the choice of escaping
>   method only opens up possibilities for
>   bugs.
>   ...
>   Only <, >, & and (in attribute values) " need escaping.

So long as the small set of special characters are encoded/escaped it should just work.

Whether you have to handle the escaping yourself is a different matter, but certainly a much more straightforward-to-solve problem.

Then just append the whole lot as a child text node to the relevant XML element.

Answer (score 1):

I know of exactly two real use cases for CDATA:

One is in an XHTML document containing script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
   function foo()
   {
      alert("You don't want <this> text escaped.");
   }
]]>
</script>
```

The other is in hand-authored XML documents where the text contains embedded markup, e.g.:

```
<p>
   A typical XML element looks like this:
</p>
<p>
   <pre>
   <![CDATA[
      <sample>
         <text>
            I'm using CDATA here so that I don't have to manually escape
            all of the special characters in this example.
         </text>
      </sample>
   ]]>
   </pre>
</p>
```

In all other cases, just letting the DOM (or the XmlWriter, or whatever tool you're using to create the XML) escape the text nodes works just fine.

Comment: A good approach to avoid needing a CDATA section around a script is to use JavaScript string literal escaping: alert("You don't want \x3Cthis\x3E text escaped.");